# Where does Boot Camp download files before making a new partition?

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp

My computer shut down in the middle of the Boot Camp process, and once I charged and re-opened it I found that about 100 GB of my storage had been taken up, but no new partition had been made. Where would these files have been downloaded?

Comment: Look under `/Library/Application Support/BootCamp/`.

Comment: I did, but it claims that `WindowsSupport.dmg` is only about 40 MB.

Comment: It may be in the `/tmp` or cache folder somewhere.  Try `/Library/Updates`. Your other option is to allow the download to complete, then delete it to free up the space.

Comment: Checked those as well, nothing, even when checking hidden folders. Boot Camp won't let me continue the previous download, only prompt me to start a new one(which I don't have the storage to do).